# Etymology of ambulance

Tags: classical-latin, etymology, history, english

For a while I have been curious about the etymology of the English word 'ambulance' since it seems to be derived from the Latin word 'ambulare' (to walk). This seems a strange origin for the word. People who require medical attention are generally unable to move, much less walk. How did this word end up having the meaning it possesses?

Comment: I have edited the title, as it wasn't clear it's relevance to the question. Feel free to undo.

Comment: @luchonacho I thought it added a bit of levity

Comment: 'walker' is not the one who require medical attention, but one who provides it (a doctor).

Comment: Interestingly, in health services, ambulatory medicine is for patients that don't need and ambulance or a hospital.

Comment: @Pere Interesting indeed! Maybe because they are able to... _ambulare_? hehe

Comment: @luchonacho - Yes, hospitals only need to ambulare when patients can't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=iau.31858000366918;view=1up;seq=445) XIX century book (a period when ambulances [were **still** driven by horses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_ambulance)):

[image]

So it might be related to the fact that ambulances were going around by walking (of horses).

It seems, however, that the word enter into English from French (which itself comes from Latin) in the XIX century. At least that's what the Concise Oxford Dictionary of English Etymology says ([here](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/the-concise-oxford-dictionary-of-english-etymology-9780192830982?cc=gb&lang=en&), although paywalled):

> moving hospital accompanying an army; vehicle to convey injured. XIX. — F. *ambulance*, repl. *hôpital ambulant* ‘walking hospital’, earlier *hôpital ambulatoire*; F. *ambulant* — prp. of L. *ambulāre* walk

More about the French word *ambulance* can be found [here](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ambulance).

Comment: Similar information not behind a paywall: https://www.etymonline.com/word/ambulance